# Get video and category in one query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 tables of data that are category ([category table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puhy8.jpg)) and video ([Video table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ndBA.jpg)) as the image below. I was querying as this picture ([Query mysqli test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KzPh.jpg)) to get the video and its catalog. Is there a way I can use only one query but still have the same result as the current query?

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$page=intval($_REQUEST['page']);
$limit=10;
$start=$page*$limit - $limit;
$video=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM video ORDER BY video_id DESC LIMIT $start,$limit");
while($r_video=mysqli_fetch_assoc($video)){
    $cat_info=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_id IN ({$r_video['video_cat']}) ORDER BY cat_sort ASC");
    while($r_cat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_info)){
        $list_cat.='<a href="/category/'.$r_cat['cat_name'].'.html">'.$r_cat['cat_name'].'</a>,';
    }
    $list_cat=substr($list_cat, 0,-1);
    echo $r_video['video_name'].'<br>'.$list_cat;
    unset($list_cat);

}
?>
```

[category table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puhy8.jpg)

[Video table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ndBA.jpg)

[Query mysqli test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KzPh.jpg)

Comment: Use a `join`. Don't use variables in your query, parameterize.

Comment: Show your code HERE in stackoverflow. Not as images, and not as external links. Links die, and then the code is lost.

Comment: Can you write it out for me? Thank you!

Comment: If you make a http://sqlfiddle.com/ sure.

Comment: "*Can you write it out for me?*" ... the hell? No. YOU have the code, YOU can copy/paste it here. Sheesh.

Comment: I edited the question! You can see it and help me. Thank you

Comment: Maybe `SELECT * FROM video as v join category as c on c.cat_id = v.video_cat` without actual sample data though can't say.

Comment: I tried your query but it does not have the same results as my current query. Because a video has more than one category.

Comment: Your DB is not designed well in that case. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 0):

I would advise a LEFT JOIN Query. For example, if you want to get all the videos from Category 1 "Music", you could perform the following:

`SELECT c.cat_name, v.video_name, v.video_url FROM video as v LEFT JOIN category as c ON c.cat_id = v.video_cat WHERE c.cat_id = 1;`

This would result in a dataset that contains:

`cat_name   video_name      video_url
 Music      Music Video 1   URL 1
 Music      Music Video 2   URL 24`

Working SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8008cc/3

In the `SELECT` statement, we calling just the columns we need, using aliases (Notice the `AS` portions). We're also gathering data from both tables based on a common column. This is the `ON` portion of the command.

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.

In PHP you can then just use 1 while statement to iterate all the results.

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE**

This is more like getting tags, then categories, as you may have multiples. See: [Get all posts for specific tag with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734598/get-all-posts-for-specific-tag-with-sql)

Comment: My video_cat is not an int, it is a string of category ids.
For example: 1,2 is cat_id of Music and Funny. That is, it has more than one category

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN the queries as others have stated, the problem that you are facing may be related to the fact that one video could be in more than one category.

In this case, I would use one analytical function to format the value as you want.

I currently cannot test this, but taking a look in the docs I would suggest that you try the GROUP_CONCAT or the CONCAT_WS after the join so you can group and return the data in the best way possible.

Just grab the queries already suggested and them group them the way you want so you can apply the functions to the group and extract the values.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I think this might be the solution for me